# db.max.anchor.length property in nutch-default.xml

Tags: java, nutch

I have db.max.anchor.length set to 5, but nutch is still fetching urls having anchor length greater that 5, 
e.g : http://mysite/somepage.htm , what is the reason for this?? I am using nutch-1.2.

Answer (score 0):

The property `db.max.anchor.length` is effective only if you create `linkdb` (inverted index). For normal crawling, it wont apply limit on size of anchor.